# It is not possible to link the solc to Geth

Tags: ubuntu, solidity

I have installed the Solidity compiler (`solc`) in ubuntu.
It is not possible to link the `solc` to `Geth`.

How can we do this?

Below are the steps I've done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solc
```

It will be displayed as follows:

```
> eth.getCompilers()
[]
```

I want to display as follows:

```
> eth.getCompilers()
['Solidity' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `solc` installed via sources, you just have to find it using the `which` command:

```
0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ which geth
/usr/bin/geth
0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ which solc
/usr/bin/solc
```

And now you can add it to `geth` using the `setSolc()` method:

```
0 ✓ user@hoster ~ $ geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.4.7-stable-667a386d/linux/go1.6.2/JIT
coinbase: 0xfcae7970392f510a985a7eaccd3820b7759d65d9
at block: 1757738 (Thu, 23 Jun 2016 18:33:28 CEST)
 datadir: /home/user/.ethereum
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> eth.getCompilers()
[]
> admin.setSolc("/usr/bin/solc")
"solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface\nVersion: 0.3.5-5f97274a/Release-Linux/g++/Interpreter\n\npath: /usr/bin/solc"
> eth.getCompilers()
["Solidity"]
>
```

Now it is linked. See also [questions tagged with `solc` on ethereum stack exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solc).